# Adding conditions at the WHERE clause gives more results

Tags: sql-server, group-by, subquery, where-clause

I use SqlServer. I have a table with lots of columns the importants of which are:

· User_name

· Partition - Date in xxxx-xx-xx format

· Game - a string that works as an ID

· Credits - A number

· Bet - Another number

· Prize - Another number

· Num_Spins - Another number

I wrote a query to select of those the ones that interest me given a specific date.

```
Select distinct CONCAT(User_Name, DATALENGTH(User_Name)) as User_name, Partition, Game, Bet, Num_spins, Credits, Prize
            from ***
            where Partition>='2019-09-01' and Partition<'2019-11-17' and Bet>0 and credits is not null
            and User_Name IN (Select distinct userName from *** where GeoIpCountryCode='ES')
```

I wish I could make that a view or something, but unfortunately I don't have the privileges to do so. Therefore, I do a subquery from it:

I want to find out of those rows, the ones whose numbers follow a certain math result: `(Credits+Bet-Prize) > 100000 and num_spins>5`

```
Select user_name, partition, count(Game) as difMachines
        FROM
        (
            Select distinct CONCAT(User_Name, DATALENGTH(User_Name)) as User_name, Partition, Game, Bet, Num_spins, Credits, Prize
            from ***
            where Partition>='2019-09-01' and Partition<'2019-11-17' and Bet>0 and credits is not null
            and User_Name IN (Select distinct userName from *** where GeoIpCountryCode='ES')
        ) as A
        where 
        (Credits+Bet-Prize) > 100000 and num_spins>5
        group by User_Name, Partition;
```

Now, I got all the information I need. I run the last query, to group_by date these results so I can analyze them:

```
Select  datepart(week,Partition) as Week, count (distinct user_name) as Users
    from (
        Select user_name, partition, count(Game) as difMachines
        FROM
        (
            Select distinct CONCAT(User_Name, DATALENGTH(User_Name)) as User_name, Partition, Game, Bet, Num_spins, Credits, Prize
            from ***
            where Partition>='2019-09-01' and Partition<'2019-11-17' and Bet>0 and credits is not null
            and User_Name IN (Select distinct userName from *** where GeoIpCountryCode='ES')
        ) as A
        where 
        (Credits+Bet-Prize) > 100000 and num_spins>5
        group by User_Name, Partition
    ) as B
    Where difMachines=1
    group by datepart(week,Partition)
    order by Week asc;
```

I know the query can be optimized, but that's not what troubles me. The problem is that when running this query, I obtain at week 36 17050 users. If I change this line `(Credits+Bet-Prize) > 100000 and num_spins>5` for this one `(Credits+Bet-Prize) > 100000` (so, I purely remove the `num_spins>5` part), I get 16800 users instead.

To sum up, I get more results by being more restrictive in my query. That does not make sense to me. Someone please can help? Head me to the right direction or something?

Thank you

Comment: Underlying data has changed? We really need sample data that replicates the problem.

Comment: Adding more restrictions _can't_ increase the size of the result set.  Either you misphrased what you did to the `WHERE` clause, or your underlying data is changing.

Comment: Hmm, you probably *could* get more results with a more restrictive `WHERE` **if** there was aggregation of some kind and that aggregated column is added/removed to the `WHERE`/`HAVING`. For example, a list of customers than have spent less than £1,000, and then a list customers than spent less than £1,000 between certain dates. The query is more restrictive, in the date period, however, as it's more restrictive more customers **won't** have spent £1,000 so more would be returned. That isn't what you're doing here though,

Comment: The underlying data seems to be the same, as I can replicate those same results no matter the time or order I run the queries. A BI colleague made me notice that the first group by is unnecesary because I'm selecting all the columns anyway, so I'll edit the question removing it, but the same happens

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I took the mentioned lane and removed the "and num_spins>5" part of it. That's literally all I did, I don't know if I phrased that correctly, but that's it.

Comment: A few red flags in your logic. Using distinct in a subquery with IN does nothing useful. Using DISTINCT and GROUP BY in the same query without an aggregrate is another concern that you struggle with writing logically correct queries. The count of games is labelled difmachines - but can you not play the same game on multiple tables / devices? Concatenating user_name and it's length in bytes is strange and suggests another kludge. But you know a specific week gives you suspicious numbers - so run queries against that week to examine the raw code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the count of result set with this filter **diffmachine=1**,isn't?. but if you remove the filter **num_spins>5** then count will increase for **diffmachine** greater than 1.here i give an example like yours

```
Declare  @t table
(
    [user_name] varchar(5), [partition] date, Game varchar(10),num_spins int
)

insert into @t
select 'a','01nov19','g1',1
union all
select 'a','01nov19','g1',2
union all
select 'a','01nov19','g1',3
union all
select 'a','01nov19','g1',4
union all
select 'a','01nov19','g1',5
union all
select 'a','01nov19','g1',6
union all
select 'b','01nov19','g1',7

select * from
(
    select [user_name],[partition],count(game) cnt
    from  @t
    where num_spins>5
    group by [user_name],[partition]
)a
where cnt=1
```

Comment: That's it, I checked it with a different difMachines number and the ones that were taken off from one subset were put in on another. Thank you! <3